# Solubility of amines

Tags: organic-chemistry

I ran across something saying that n-butanamine is miscible in water while butanol is only partially soluble. Is this correct? Can anyone offer an explanation? I would have guessed that the decreased polarity of the amine relative to the alcohol would have resulted in lower solubility for n-butanamine.

Comment: Tendency to form n-butylamonium cation may play a role too.

Comment: $n$- butanamineis only a weak base. We would not expect much of it to dissociate into ions.

Answer (score 2):

The different solubility of certain alcohols versuses corresponding amines cannot explain simply by considering the electronegativity advantage of oxygen over nitrogen alone to make hydrogen bonding. For example, intermolecular forces between neat amine is weaker (e.g., boiling point of 1-aminobutane is $\pu{78 ^\circ C}$) than that in alcohols (e.g., boiling point of 1-butanol is $\pu{118 ^\circ C}$). To dissolve either compound in water, those corresponding intermolecular forces should be broken before making new intermolecular forces with water molecules, thus, amine has the advantage over that for having weaker intermolecular bonds. My speculation can be supported by [following data](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Eastern_Wyoming_College/EWC%3A_CHEM_2300_-_Introductory_Organic_(Budhi)/4%3A_Organic_Acids_and_Bases_and_Some_of_Their_Derivatives/4.11%3A_Physical_Properties_of_Amines), which shows the different solubilities of triethylamine in water (boiling point: $\pu{90 ^\circ C}$; solubility in water $\pu{14 g}$ in $\pu{100 mL}$ water) compared to that of dipropylamine (boiling point: $\pu{111 ^\circ C}$; solubility in water $\pu{4 g}$ in $\pu{100 mL}$ water).

Also, primary amine such as 1-aminobutane has two $\ce{N-H}$ bonds to make hydrogen bonding compared to one $\ce{O-H}$ bond in 1-butanol. Again, advantage: amine.

It's worth noting that, as Poutnik pointed out in the comment section, the tendency to form *n*-butylammonium cation may play a role too:
$$\ce{n-Bu-NH2 + H2O <=> n-Bu-NH3+ + OH-}$$